# datagridview and NumericUpDown?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, numericupdown

I have a `NumericUpDown` box and depending on its value, I want to insert the letter into a `DataGridView`. Here is my code, but it does not insert into the column I want.

```
if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value < 50)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("F");
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 50 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 64)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("D");
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 64 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 68)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("D+");
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 68 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 72)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("C-");
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 72 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 76)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("C");
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 76 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 80)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("C+");
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 80 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 84)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("B-");
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 88 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 92)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("B");
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 92 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 96)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("B+");
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 96 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 100)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("A-");
}
```

Comment: What is happening instead? And what do you want to happen?

Comment: what happen is that the letter inserted in wrrong row and cell man 
and what i want is to correct it to insert it in its real culumn :(

Comment: Right, but which cell do you want the letter to go in under each circumstance? We can't see your table and we have no idea where you want these letters to go.

Comment: In order to help you, we need a better explanation of the expected behavior.

Comment: ill attached photo now for more explanation man

Comment: I cant upload photo is there a way to show you what i want ???

Comment: here is the photo  http://www.4shared.com/photo/-DYrLLDq/Capture.html?

Comment: What row do you want it to go in if not a new row?

Comment: actully the F letter should inserted into "mark as letter" culumn is it clear now man I am relly hopless because I am working with datagridview for the first time

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are more interested in the `Cells` values rather than the `Rows` values. Try something like this:

```
        if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value < 50)
        {
            int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = "F";
        }
        else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 50 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 64)
        {
            int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = "D";
        }
```

Update:
Judging by your picture, it looks like you are only concerned about EDITING a row and not ADDING a row. If this is the case, you need to keep track of which row you are concerned with and which column you are concerned with (please change the variable names to something that makes more sense for your application):

```
int indexOfRowICareAbout = 0;
int indexOfColumnIStoreLettersIn = 4; //Judging by your picture 

if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value < 50)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[indexOfRowICareAbout].Cells[indexOfColumnIStoreLettersIn].Value = "F";
}
else if (MarkNumericUpDown.Value > 50 && MarkNumericUpDown.Value <= 64)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[indexOfRowICareAbout].Cells[indexOfColumnIStoreLettersIn].Value = "D";
}
```

Comment: thanks man but isn't working in the code i write the letter inserted in the next row and first cell 
and ur code has move it one cell so its inserted in next row but second cell

Comment: You don't have to use the values for column index that I used. I was just showing an example.

Comment: sure I tried to change the values but all that change is only the cell not the row... 
it's not inserted in the same row where should it do

Comment: sure man I tried to change the values but its not inserted in the first row all its change when i change the values is the culumn 
ill attached photo now for more explanation